# How can I access raw data from the altimeter sensor on apple watch?

Tags: apple-watch, core-motion, raw-data, cmaltimeter

I am trying to get the data from the barometric altimeter sensor on apple watch.

I tried using the apple documentation (it worked for accelerometer and gyroscope) but when I tried to use the methods documented in the CMAltimeter class, it did not recognize any of it (related to the altimeter).